# Redundant type arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have written this class in IntelliJ.

```
public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.<Number>foo(0);
        Main.<Integer>foo(0);
    }

    static <T> void foo(T t) {}
}
```

The line `Main.<Number>foo(0);` does not generate any message, but on next line I get the message

> explicit type argument can be inferred. 
>   This inspection reports all calls to parametrized methods where
>   explicit argument types can be omitted, since they will be
>   unambiguously inferred by the compiler.

This doesn't make any sense to me at all. My understanding is that all type arguments are erased, so it shouldn't matter whether the type argument is ambiguous. As far as I can tell the only reason for ever supplying a type argument when invoking a generic method with void return type is to convince the compiler that a type `T` exists within the required bounds. Beyond that it shouldn't make any difference what type argument you actually supply. So if the type argument is redundant in the second case it should be redundant in the first. Can anyone explain how the rules for when these messages appear work, and why in this case the rules should even depend on the type argument supplied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen that message, but it looks like a warning.

First observation is that this coming from the Intellij compiler.  When I compiled this using the Java 8 `javac`, there is no such warning message.

The other thing to note is that in this case it makes no difference what type the compiler infers for `T` here.  I think that is what the compiler is telling you.

It *could* matter if the method returned `T` and you assigned the result to a variable (for example).  For example:

```
   Integer i = Main.<Integer>foo(0);  // OK
   i = Main.foo(0);                   // OK
   i = Main.<Long>foo(0L);            // Error
   i = Main.foo(0L);                  // Different error message.
```

In the 3rd case, the (`javac`) compiler says that `Long` can't be assigned to `Integer`.

In the last case, the (`javac`) compiler infers that `foo` will return a `Long` and it says that the inferred type cannot be assigned.

---

> I can't see why you should ever have to provide a type argument.

Consider the case where the result of the `foo` call is used as an argument of an overloaded method, and you need a specific result type to get Java to call the right overload.

It is also worth noting that Java 8's type inference is more sophisticated than in earlier versions.  There may be cases with older versions of Java where the inference needed some help in the form of an explicit type parameter.

Comment: I don't get that warning in Eclipse either.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a warning saying that specifying the type is unnecessary.

Since `T` is an object, and cannot be a primitive, the `0` argument will be boxed to an `Integer`. This means that the compiler will infer that `T` means `Integer`, so specifying it is redundant.

The argument is boxed to an Integer regardless of the type argument you specify. E.g. `Test.<Long>foo(0)` will not compile, because `Integer` is not compatible with `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on generic methods https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

> Notice that we don't have to pass an actual type argument to a generic method. The compiler infers the type argument for us, based on the types of the actual arguments. It will generally infer the most specific type argument that will make the call type-correct.

Since Integer is the most specific type already in your case, it is redundant to specify it.  Since Number is a more general type, it is not redundant.

Also, you are correct that there is no runtime difference in the two invocations due to type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here have explained why the type parameter can be omitted.

As for why this is a warning in the first place, it's because your code is redundant. The [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle says you should never write redundant code, so your IDE's compiler is helpfully warning you that you've written redundant, unnecessary code.

Even (some would say especially) in cases where it doesn't make a difference to the compiled result, or to the behavior at runtime, it is still worthwhile to remove redundant code. So I think this is a good warning and it's probably best to follow its advice.